# How do I run migrations on GCloud SQL instance?

Tags: mysql, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to run a migration on the GCloud MySQL instance for my site.

I have already tried making a new bucket on the GCloud console and importing my local MySQL dump into that and then adding that to the MySQL instance. It didn't work.
I also saw someone recommending to connect to the GC using the GC proxy and Google Compute Engine. I am new to this so I couldn't follow along very well, and I found out that App and Compute Engine are two different things.

Here's my requirements file;

```
asn1crypto==0.24.0
cffi==1.12.2
cryptography==2.6.1
Django==2.1.7
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
freeze==1.0.10
mysql==0.0.2
mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1
Pillow==6.0.0
psycopg2==2.8.1
pycparser==2.19
PyMySQL==0.9.3
pytz==2018.9
six==1.12.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will either need direct access via public IP to your Cloud SQL instance or use this tutorial to setup Cloud SQL Proxy with a Service Account and direct the SQL connector to that proxy https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app

Comment: Thanks, that documentation link solved it. I had some issues with the ./cloudsql command. it needed the JSON file for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Run the DB proxy (./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=xyz:xyz=tcp:5431) and then run "python3 manage.py migrate"